# I wanted to search and replace the first instance of "//window" using sed in linux

Tags: sed

```
sed 's!//window!window!' index.html
```

Above is the command which replaces all instances of `//window`. I just wanted to replace the first instance or only the first occurrence of `//window` to `window`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using GNU `sed`, try -

```
sed '0,/\/\/window/s//window/' index.html
```

This code will replace the first instance of `//window` with `window`  and stop thereafter.

Comment: If you don't want to escape as much, you can use `0,\|//window|` for the address range.

Comment: That's precisely the secret sauce here; it selects the range from beginning of file through to the first occurrence of the pattern. This is a GNU `sed` extension.

Comment: Now how do I target for second occurrence only? Say to change "window" to "//window"

Comment: You would add `2` at the end. So, for the above example, it would be - `sed '0,/\/\/window/s//window/2'`